# format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 3 has type 'int' [-Wformat] in fprintf

Tags: c, types, arguments, printf

i have the following method contents:

```
FILE *file;
file = fopen("customers.dat", "w");
PList *list;
list = &customers;
fprintf(file, "%s", *(list->person.name));
```

error given on the fprintf line::

```
format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 3 has type 'int' [-Wformat]
```

I have the following structs:

PList:

```
typedef struct PList{
    Person person;
    struct PList *nextPerson;  //  set to NULL by default <<<<<
}PList;
```

Person:

```
typedef struct Person{
    char name[100]; // Left as "" if empty Person
    PersonID ID;
    float amountOwed;
}Person;
```

PersonID:

```
typedef struct PersonID{
    char letter;
    int number; // 7 digits
}PersonID;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drop the `*`:

```
fprintf(file, "%s", *(list->person.name));
                    ^
```